# Count numbers with Hamming distance less than or equal than given k from a given set of integers

Tags: binary-data, hamming-distance, edit-distance

I admit that this problem is part (although small) of school programming assignment, but I wasn't able to find much of a hint online and my solutions are very slow so far.

Here is my problem defined more precisely: 
Given a vector of integers v and integer k, count how many integers exist such that their Hamming distance (bits you need to flop to get an original integer) from all integers from v is less than or equal k.

This means that given v = {0000, 0001} and k = 2, result numbers are {0000, 0001, 1001, 0101, 0011, 1000, 0100, 0010} and count is therefore 8 (really hope I'm not miscalculating here).

My approach so far is to generate all potential numbers from v[0] and then compare them with other numbers from the vector. In code, it looks like this:

```
void CRig::Solve(AFITCoin x) {
// Get information from problem pointer
vector<uint32_t> &strings = (*x).m_Vectors;
const int max_dist = (*x).m_DistMax;

// Generate all potential strings
set<uint32_t> validStrings;
validStrings.insert(strings[0]);
generateValidStrings(strings[0], validStrings, max_dist);

// Compare generated strings to strings in vector
// and increment count if Hamming distance is in bound
for (uint32_t i : validStrings) {
    bool is_in_distance = true;
    for (uint32_t num : strings) {
        int hamm_dist = hammingDistance((int)i, (int)num);
        if (hamm_dist > max_dist) {
            is_in_distance = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(is_in_distance) (*x).m_Count++;
}

}


void generateValidStrings(uint32_t num, set<uint32_t> &validStrings, int dist_left) {
// Base case: Current distance is out of bounds
if (!dist_left)
    return;

// Flipping one bit at a time and proceed to bigger distance
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    uint32_t newNum = num;
    newNum ^= (1u << i);
    validStrings.insert(newNum);
    generateValidStrings(newNum, validStrings, dist_left - 1);
}
}
```

I have no idea how to make this code much more efficient, so any help is appreciated!